# Frame is not responding when I use cv2. Videocature()

Tags: python, opencv

```py
Import numpy as no
Import cv2
Cap=cv2.videocapture(0) 
While true:
  Frame=cap.read() 
Cv2. Imshow(frame)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and the [Formatting Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). When you're done, [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things incorrect in your code.

`cap.read()` returns a tuple of 2 values: a variable that holds whether a frame was successfully grabbed and the actual frame itself. You need to account for the 2 values that are returned.

The `imshow` function opens a window to display the frame. Besides the frame it requires a name for the window.

You need to add a `waitKey` to the loop. This is necessary for openCV to be able to draw the window with the frame on screen.

I've modified your code below. [This tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) can further help you out with question on many of the basic procedures in openCV. You learn most by trying to find the answers on the web yourself, before asking others ;)

```
import numpy as no
import cv2
cap=cv2.videocapture(0) 
while true:
        ret, frame=cap.read() 
        # if a frame was succesfully grabbed
        if ret:
                # display the frame in a window called frame
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
```